# what does clicking on a star "This is a favourite question" do?

Tags: support

I have noticed a star below the up & down vote buttons that says "This is a favourite question (click again to undo)"

what does clicking on a question's star "This is a favourite question" do?

is it a bookmark feature? or
to alert other users that this question is a "favourite"? - in which case, what does "favourite" mean?

I searched in Help Centre for "favourite question" but did not find any relevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily find any favorite marked question in your profile, so it's kind of a bookmark feature:

[image: snapshot]

You can also see how many users also did mark this question as favorite, which *might* be a sign of how valued that answer is.

Comment: FYI - found a related question: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6242/does-marking-a-question-as-favourite-allow-tracking-its-activity?rq=1

Comment: It's actually more than a bookmark.  It allows you to track activity on the thread, like the posting of new answers.  Favorites with activity since the last time you checked the post get highlighted in the list.  This is good information to share with users who post answers that are "me, too" questions or queries about whether the OP ever found a solution.  You can tell them to favorite the question and they'll be alerted to new answers on the favorites tab of their profile page.